# Way too fast scrolling in Emacs on Win10

Tags: windows-10, mouse, emacs, touchpad, scrolling

My question is almost the same as this one: [Way too fast scrolling in Emacs on OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/1133436/way-too-fast-scrolling-in-emacs-on-osx)

I am using Emacs 26.1 on a Windows 10 machine. The scrolling speed when using the trackpad is much higher than when using the mouse. I tried with the following lines in my init.el:

```
(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 1)))
(setq mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil)
(setq mouse-wheel-follow-mouse 't)
(setq scroll-step 1)
```

... to no avail: the trackpad will always scroll much faster than the mouse. In other programs, both the mouse and trackpad scrolling speeds are reasonable.

It seems that the trackpad is triggering much more scroll events when in Emacs, compared to other programs.

I'm not interested in "smooth scrolling", I just want to scroll at reasonable speeds.

Comment: Perhaps try asking in [emacs.se]

Comment: I'm not sure. After googling, it seems that this might be a Windows bug that does not only occur with Emacs.

Comment: This happens to me too, and I found that holding Control slows it down. In the customize option for Mouse Wheel Scroll Amount there was an entry that said to scroll by a full screen when holding Control, which is the opposite of what I saw. Removing that entry make it scroll slowly again.